# Consulta MySQL Y PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Cordial saludo.

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta en *MySQL* y *PHP*, lo debo hacer es validar un número de documento si este existe en la bd, lo redirecciona a una página o a un formulario, si no esta registrado debe de enviar un mensaje que diga "*No esta registrado*", al hacer las pruebas le escribo cualquier cosa y este me envía a la pagina, es como si no hiciera nada la consulta.

### Formulario

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm-validar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
         <h2>Validar</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form action="archivo_validar.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="numerodocumento" class="form-control" id="control2_nombre" placeholder="No. CC" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="submit" name="btn">Validar</button>
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Consulta

```
<?php
$cc=$_POST['numerodocumento'];
    include 'conexion.php';
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM profesores WHERE numerocc = '$cc'");
    
if($consulta){

    header('location: https://google.com');
}
else
echo "Usted no esta registrado";
?>
```

Comment: Tienes algún error? `numerocc` es entero?

Answer (score 0):

**La consulta `mysqli_query` trae valores no booleanos,  no un string.**
Debes recorrer la consulta realizada, para poder comparar los valores deseados.
No puedes solo usar $consulta como tu resultado.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo $row['classtype']."<br>";
}
```

Ya luego de haber obtenido los valores, los puedes comparar en un IF.